# TCP state for a given slanger/pusher channel?

Tags: ruby, tcp, websocket, connection, pusher

We are building a large slanger cluster and would like to use websocket TCP as client connectivity indicator, so whenever a client is offline we could tell from the channel state. Is there an API to check online/offline status of a channel?

Besides that, is there a way to get the TCP fd of the websocket beneath a channel? So I can grab some statistics of that long connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK after reading through Slanger's source code I have concluded that it is not possible. I modified slanger/lib/subscription.rb to have my own customized tcp status exposed via http api.